# Wrong frequency response of an active HPF filter

Tags: filter, active-filter, high-pass-filter

I am trying to simulate an active high pass filter on OrCad, but the frequency response of it looks like a band pass filter, does anyone know why ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe, your OPA-Model has a 100kHz bandwidth. Maybe, you could also have a look at https://www.electronicshub.org/active-high-pass-filter/

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent that was really the problem thank you very much :3

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent Maybe as a system, but op-amps are usually not rated by bandwidth like that. It might have a GBW of 2 MHz, which means it can achieve a gain of 2 at 100 kHz, or then it is some other limitation like slew rate. So unlikely that the op-amp has a 100 kHz bandwidth.

Comment: Why are you simulating with an opamp that has no datasheet and no specs?

Comment: @Audioguru I'm actually kinda new to op amps and electronics in general, and there is a lot I still need to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the mystery part you used does not have the bandwidth or slew rate to be capable of 20V output amplitude at beyond about 100 kHz so it can't output 20V amplitude at higher frequencies it is capable of.

Answer (score 0):

Every opamp has a datasheet detailing all its specs like this:
[image: opamps]